# Is there a way to parametise which modules to load in Dojo?

Tags: module, dojo, amd

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this, but I'm not sure how to go about it:

```
define([
    // Load basic modules that are always used
], function (one, two, ...) {
    if (a) {
        // Load this extra module as "extraModule"
    }
    else {
        // Load that extra module as "extraModule"
    }
    // Be able to use functions from extraModule without worrying
    // exactly what they do
    extraModule.doTheThing();
```

Then the two options for extraModule would behave as though they were objects inheriting from the same abstract class.

Does anyone know if this is possible with Dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest way to achieve this is by doing the following:

```js
define([ "one", "two", "extraModule1", "extraModule2" ], function(one, two, extra1, extra2) {
    var extra = null;
    if (a) {
        extra = extra1;
    } else {
        extra = extra2;
    }
});
```

So you just load both modules and pick the one you need afterwards.